# Update fields in table based on previous field records

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table of records for pay periods with fields WeekStart and WeekEnd populated for ever fiscal year. In my application a user should be able to update the first WeekEnd date for a given fiscal year and that should in turn update subsequent records WeekStart date by adding 1 day to the Previous WeekEnd date and for the same records's WeekEnd date, add 13 days to the new WeekStart date.

This is part of a Stored Procedure written in SQL Server 2016.

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[staffing_BiweeklyPPCopy]  
SET 
[WeekStart] = DATEADD(DD, 1, LAG([WeekEnd], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [ID])), 
[WeekEnd] = DATEADD(DD, 14, LAG([WeekEnd], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]))
WHERE
[FiscalYear] = @fiscalyear
```

Original Table contents shown below...

```
ID  WeekStart   WeekEnd
163 2018-10-01  2018-10-13
164 2018-10-14  2018-10-27
165 2018-10-28  2018-11-10
166 2018-11-11  2018-11-24
167 2018-11-25  2018-12-08
168 2018-12-09  2018-12-22
169 2018-12-23  2019-01-05
170 2019-01-06  2019-01-19
171 2019-01-20  2019-02-02
172 2019-02-03  2019-02-16
173 2019-02-17  2019-03-02
174 2019-03-03  2019-03-16
175 2019-03-17  2019-03-30
176 2019-03-31  2019-04-13
177 2019-04-14  2019-04-27
178 2019-04-28  2019-05-11
179 2019-05-12  2019-05-25
180 2019-05-26  2019-06-08
181 2019-06-09  2019-06-22
182 2019-06-23  2019-07-06
183 2019-07-07  2019-07-20
184 2019-07-21  2019-08-03
185 2019-08-04  2019-08-17
186 2019-08-18  2019-08-31
187 2019-09-01  2019-09-14
188 2019-09-15  2019-09-28
189 2019-09-29  2019-09-30
```

For example if a user updates the weekend date for record ID 163 to '2018-10-14', the table will update as follows..

```
ID  WeekStart   WeekEnd
163 2018-10-01  2018-10-14
164 2018-10-15  2018-10-28
165 2018-10-29  2018-11-11
166 2018-11-12  2018-11-25
167 2018-11-26  2018-12-09
.
.
.
189 2019-09-30  2019-09-30
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How often are you changing the structure of your fiscal years? Isn't that just static data?

Comment: The structure will not change much however if a user initially creates pay periods by choosing the wrong first weekend date of the fiscal year, they need to be able to modify that.

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2012, I believe new functions for Lag and Lead were introduced to fetch previous and Next records in a record set however I'm not well versed in it's use. Trying it out as shown in my Update example threw an exception stating that the Lag() function cannot be used without a Select Statement.